# Spring @Autowired OK on JUnit, NPE on main class

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

I have a open source project hosted at [this](https://github.com/robertobado/open-restaurant-core) github. I am facing a weird scenario. I found many people who could make @Autowired Spring annotation work on their main classes but not on their JUnit test classes. My problem is the other way around. I can successfully use @Autowired in my JUnit test class but when a test calls my main class, the dependencies don't get injected there. Here is my context (simplified version):

Login Class:

```
package net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource;

@Path("/login")
@Component
@Transactional
@Singleton
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class Login extends BaseResource{

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @POST
    public Response post(String requestBody){

        ...

        //NullPointerException
        User user = userDAO.loadByCompanyIdAndLogin(companyId, login);
    }

    ...

}
```

LoginTest Class:

```
package net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
public class LoginTest extends BaseResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    ...

    @Test
    public void testInvalidPassword() {

    ....

    // Works perfectly!
    userDAO.save(user);

    ....

    }

}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:configuration.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.openrally.restaurant.core" />

    <import resource="db-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

I am searching for a solution for a few days now. From what I could find so far, most of the people who have `@Autowired` problems dont have either `<context:annotation-config />`  or `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` in their spring xml or dont have a `@Component` family annotation in the class they want DI to take place, and as you can see, they are both there :(. I have only one `applicationContext.xml` in my project which suits for both runtime and test (I have distinct configuration.properties to set database credentials and log levels differently, but no spring configuration there)

I'm using:

```
Spring: 3.1.0.RELEASE
JUnit: 4.10
Jersey: 1.11
CLIB: 2.2.2
```

Any ideas, and I mean ANY :), is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The following logs come up when I run the test:

```
2012-03-27 07:37:02,457 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'login'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,457 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'login'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,459 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Found injected element on class [net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login]: AutowiredFieldElement for private net.openrally.restaurant.core.persistence.dao.ConfigurationDAO net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login.configurationDAO
2012-03-27 07:37:02,459 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Found injected element on class [net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login]: AutowiredFieldElement for private net.openrally.restaurant.core.persistence.dao.UserDAO net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login.userDAO
2012-03-27 07:37:02,459 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'login' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2012-03-27 07:37:02,459 TRACE [main] org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults - Getting BeanInfo for class [net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login]
2012-03-27 07:37:02,462 TRACE [main] org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults - Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login]
2012-03-27 07:37:02,462 TRACE [main] org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults - Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
2012-03-27 07:37:02,462 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'login': AutowiredFieldElement for private net.openrally.restaurant.core.persistence.dao.ConfigurationDAO net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login.configurationDAO
2012-03-27 07:37:02,462 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'configurationDAO'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,462 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'login' to bean named 'configurationDAO'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,463 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'login': AutowiredFieldElement for private net.openrally.restaurant.core.persistence.dao.UserDAO net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login.userDAO
2012-03-27 07:37:02,463 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userDAO'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,463 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'login' to bean named 'userDAO'
2012-03-27 07:37:02,464 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'login' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
2012-03-27 07:37:02,464 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy - Creating CGLIB2 proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login@60532a0a]
2012-03-27 07:37:02,465 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response net.openrally.restaurant.core.exposure.resource.Login.post(java.lang.String)
```

Could Spring be creating my bean correctly but Jersey using its own non-autowired instance?

Comment: Is there any sort of conflict between `@Component` and `@Singleton` on your bean ? And how is loaded your `applicationContext.xml` file for runtime ?

Comment: Hello nico_ekito, thanks for your input. The `@Singleton` is just an optimization. I tried removing it after your comment but no luck... The `appliationContext.xml` is in the resources folder and project has spring dependencies controlled by maven. I plan to use jetty as a web container but for the tests I am using Grizzly Web Container from Jersey.

Comment: But how your `applicationContext.xml` file is loaded in your runtime app ? By a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` ? By a webapp ?

Comment: Currently. my applicationContext.xml is loaded by junit tests bootstrap. For production it will be loaded by the web container. I didn't get much in detail regarding to that... How could I check if it is being loaded properly? Looks seem to indicate so...

Comment: If you do not use any context loader, it will not load. In a web application, use a `ContextLoaderListener` : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-create

Comment: Hello nico_ekito, after reading the documentation I added a servlet loader to my web.xml, but unfortunately that didn't help. From what I could see in logs, Spring is finding my resource class and is injecting dependencies, but test isnt retrieving spring bean to process my request. I will investigate further and post my findings. If you have any further tip, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a while, I could not find a way to make GrizzlyWeb use the context loaded by spring, so I tried to find an alternative solution.

I then found [Hifaces20](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/Hifaces20/Hifaces20+Testing+package+-+testing%2C+tracing+and+debugging+web+applications+with+Jetty), which will let you start and stop a jetty instance, within the same JVM (which means you may, for instance, use a memory database that will be seen both by your tests and your application)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and later found that it was a developer issue :)

I was creating a new object instead of using the spring bean.

Lets say class `MyService` autowires a dao class `MyDao myDaoBean`. Now lets say I want to use `MyService` in `MyController`, I should wire in the Spring bean `myServiceSpringBean`. If I try to create a new `myServiceObject` then Spring doesn't wire the `myDaoBean` into the `myServiceObject` because it's not aware about that new service object.

And that leads to `myDaoBean` being null.